# Ratio of CDF to PDF increasing?

Tags: derivatives, normal-distribution

Let $\Phi(x)$ be a cumulative normal distribution function and $\phi(x)$ the associated probability density function.

Is the ratio $\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}$ increasing in x?

Numerically it seems to be true. Is there any ways to prove it analytically?

Thanks

Comment: Sure--simply differentiate twice, using $\Phi'(x)=\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi'(x)=-x\varphi(x)$.

Comment: @Did why would be the derivative of the pdf satisfy this in general $\varphi'(x)=-x\varphi(x)$? the OP is not talking just about the normal distribution...although this might be a good starter to check a special case

Comment: Alex, are you talking about a general situation are just about the normal distribution?

Comment: @user190080 $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ (or $\phi$) are customarily used for the standard normal CDF and PDF so I assumed this was so here. This, plus the fact that the result is absurd in general. But you are quite right that the OP should make this clear.

Comment: normal distribution

Comment: OP: Add this to the question please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inverse Mill's ratio is defined as
$$
\lambda(x)=\frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}.
$$
For answering the question, it suffices to show that $\lambda'(x)<0$. Note that the p.d.f. of standard normal $\phi$ is differentiable. Thus we can apply quotient rule to it
$$
\lambda'(x)=\frac{\phi'(x)\Phi(x)-\phi(x)^2}{\Phi(x)^2}=\frac{-x\phi(x)\Phi(x)-\phi(x)^2}{\Phi(x)^2}=-\lambda(x)(x+\lambda(x)).
$$
Observe that
$$
\phi'(x)=-x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\lbrace -\frac{x^2}{2}\right\rbrace=-x\phi(x).
$$
It is clear that
$$
x+\lambda(x)>0,\quad \forall x\geq 0.
$$
The challenge is to show that
$$
-x+\lambda(-x)>0,\quad \forall x>0.
$$
Here we exploit two facts:

1. normal distribution is symmetrical around $0$.
2. the inverse Mill's ratio is the expectation of the truncated normal
   $$
   \frac{\phi(x)}{1-\Phi(x)}=E[X|X>x],\quad X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).
   $$

Thus the condition we want to show can be written as
$$
E[X|X>x]=\frac{\phi(x)}{1-\Phi(x)}=\frac{\phi(-x)}{\Phi(-x)}=\lambda(-x)>x,\quad \forall x>0.
$$
If this is not immediate to you, invoke Chebychev's inequality to get
$$
E[X|X>x]\geq x.
$$
For strict inequality, argue by contradiction. Suppose $E[X|X>x]=x$, then it is necessary that
$$
\int_{x}^\infty (X-x)d\Phi(X)=0,
$$
which implies that $X=x$ except on a set of $\Phi$ measure zero. But this is clearly false that we can always find a set with strictly positive $\Phi$ measure for which $X>x$ given any $x$.

Comment: Thanks Xiao Yang. This proof works!

Answer (score 1):

As in Conrado Costa's answer:
$$
\Bigl(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\Bigr)' = 1 + x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} \tag{1}
$$
and the RHS is clearly positive for $x\ge0$.

For $x<0$ write
$$
1 + x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}
  =  \frac{x}{\phi(x)} \, \Psi(x) ,
$$
where
$$
\Psi(x) := \frac{\phi(x)}{x} + \Phi(x) .
$$

$\Psi(x)$ is negative for $x<0$
since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\Psi(x) = 0$ and
$\Psi'(x) := -\frac{\phi(x)}{x^2} < 0$,
hence the RHS of (1) is positive for $x<0$ too.

Comment: This is a simpler proof, but there is an error (I think that this is a typo). The equation is $1 + x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} = \frac{x}{\phi(x)} \Psi(x)$. In other words, the numerator and denominators are exchanged in the right hand side of the second equation. The proof is then correct.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBaudin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a simpler way, but here is a thought. Use the relations $ \Phi(x)' = \phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)'= -x\phi(x)$

$$\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)' = \frac{\Phi(x)'\phi(x) - \Phi(x)\phi(x)'}{\phi(x)^2} = \frac{\phi^2(x) + x \Phi(x)\phi(x)}{\phi(x)^2} = 1 + x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}$$

If $\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)' \geq 0$ we are done.

But note that since $x$ can take negative values, we can't be sure that $1 + x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} \geq 0$.

If $1 + x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} = 0$ then

$$\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)'' =  \left(1 + x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)' = \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} + x\left(1 + x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right) = \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} \geq 0 $$

Therefore once we prove that $\lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)' \geq 0$ then we will have proved that $\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)' \geq 0$ holds for every $x\in \Bbb{R}$

Therefore we calculate:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}1 +  x \frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} = 1 + \lim_{x \to -\infty}x\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-u^2/2}\, du}{e^{-x^2/2}}  = 1 + \lim_{x \to -\infty}\int_{-\infty}^x xe^{-(u^2 - x^2)/2}\, du  = *$$
And 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^x xe^{-(u^2 - x^2)/2}\, du &= -\int_x^{\infty} xe^{-(u^2 - x^2)/2}\, du \\
&= -\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-((x+h)^2 - x^2)/2}\, dh  = \int_0^{\infty} -x e^{-h^2/2} e^{ - xh}\, dh \xrightarrow[x \to \infty]{} 0
\end{align}

Once $xe^{ - xh}\xrightarrow[x \to \infty]{} 0$ Now note that

$$ 1 + \lim_{x \to -\infty}\int_{-\infty}^x xe^{-(u^2 - x^2)/2}\, du = 1 - \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^x xe^{-(u^2 - x^2)/2}\, du = 1 \geq 0$$

Comment: What about on the interval $]-\infty,0[$, the function could still be negative. This reasoning works only if the function is monotonically decreasing on that interval but that is not so trivial to show...

Comment: I think I missed your point, Since we showed that for $x< -R$ $\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)' \geq 0$ and that if ever $\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)' = 0$ then let $x^* = \inf\{x, \left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)' = 0\}$ Once  $\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)''>0$ this implies that at some smaller point $z$ $\left(\frac{\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)'(z) < 0$ wich is a contradiction, so the function is increasing. What do you think?