# Why inverse Mills ratio for normal distribution is 1-Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, lipschitz-functions, gaussian-integral

The inverse Mill ratio for a standard normal distribution is:
$$
IMR(x) = \frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)},
$$
where $\phi(x)$ is the pdf of standard normal distribution and $\Phi(x)$ is the cdf of standard normal distribution.
The paper ["Nonasymptotic analysis of semiparametric regression models with high-dimensional parametric coefficients"](https://169fd346-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/yingzhu1215/home/AOS1528.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7coZzrULs4oF_eHxclg8OwEyIX7IVIiXZRz5KDq6XlvbVCTfkNgJKaqdKnWwXgKLb8q25JCNenrlck25Kn21rkHBveX1VIHRpdkWmBnDDQpc05SQts2d5ojlIr3X4MwD5f12X9hmdSbHZdECiJwKrrO6to1vf_pKpjcAfx4FSmhmP9CqaUdtoJj9lCfxYe4jmBiWeNZQ-mZg6w4NAVBisZveYAWyrg%3D%3D&attredirects=0) by Ying Zhu suggests that this function is 1-Liphshits continuous (see note at page 2290):
$$
|IMR(x) - IMR(y)| \leq |x - y|.
$$

How one should rigorously prove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse Mill ratio for a standard normal distribution is usually denoted by $\lambda(x)$
and verifies
$$\lambda'(x) \in (-1,0) \quad \forall x.$$

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1367026 for a proof of $\lambda'(x)<0$
and  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3118157 for a proof of $\lambda'(x)>-1$.